# Trouble adding a tools dependency with Gradle for LibGDX

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm following along in *Learn LibGDX Game Developer 2nd Edition* for a class. I'm using Eclipse. We're making a game for the desktop (Android and all disabled). We used Gradle as well. I come to this paragraph...

> For Gradle users, adding gdx-tools is easy; we just need to add the
>   following highlighted line to the build.gradle file in C:/libgdx:

```
project(":desktop") {
...
compile "com.badlogic.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```

> Make sure that you are editing under the section project(":desktop").
>   After editing, we need to refresh our dependencies. To do this,
>   right-click on the CanyonBunny-desktop project and go to the Refresh
>   All option in the Gradle menu. Make sure that you are connected to the
>   Internet because Eclipse will download the relevant dependencies.

My build.gradle under project(":desktop") method is the following...

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogic.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

I also just built a dummy LibGDX project with tools enabled to make sure I was adding the code to the right section, which I was.

After doing that, I refreshed gradle by right clicking my dependency Gradle (STS) -> Refresh All

Now when I add in some imports from that tools dependency I thought I added, my runner class cannot find it.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker;
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker.Settings;
```

Any help? Let me know if you need more info, I tried to be as detail as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book has a typo, it is suppose to be...

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```